# UserDefaults not working not returning expected result

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am building an app and began implementing UserDefaults.  It didn't work so I made a test app to simplify things and test my understanding.  It works in that app but not the one I am developing.

This question has sort of been asked before but I could not find anything helpful.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("TEST", forKey: "test")
//does not work

let test = "TEST"
UserDefaults.standard.set(test, forKey: "test")
//does not work

UserDefaults.standard.set(test, forKey: "test")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
//synchronize is legacy and not needed
//also does not work
```

However, the exact same code does work in my test app.  I uninstalled the app from the simulator, restarted my computer, etc.  No luck.

The only thing I can think of is that, I added core data manually to this project after Xcode stubbed it out.  I am pretty sure that I did that correctly but could something in AppDelegate.swift be affecting UserDefaults?

To be clear, after setting:
    UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "test")
    //returns false

PS I tagged nsuserdefaults, I am not sure if that was right or not.  I just using Swift objects as shown in the above code.

Comment: Show actual code fully demonstrating your issue. Simply showing a call to `set` and then stating "does not work" isn't a sufficient problem statement. In what way doesn't it work? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: after setting it: 

    UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "test") returns false

Comment: That's because you are storing a string for that key, not a `Bool`. The `String` "test" does not evaluate to the `Bool` "true" so you get back `false`. If you want to read back a `Bool`, set a `Bool`, not a `String`.

Comment: Nice, thank you so much.  I thought I saw .bool() used that way somewhere.  Must have been wrong.